# How to secure my SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I am an entry level developer and i am developing an Android App which completely relies on the data which i store in SQLite database. I dont want any others to watch my data in the database. The application is simple. I package my database with the application and code reads data from this database(Offline mode). In this mode, i update data very rarely.
Can someone please suggest what are the better approaches.

Below is what i tried:
Tried to use SQLCipher, but it ends up writing "pass phrase" / "password" some where in the code. Anyone who can look at my code can easily see my data with "password".

2nd Approach what i am thinking is, how can i make this database online? Meaning do i need to take DB Server or AWS machine and all data retrieved from this DB Server online? If this approach is better, I am planning to have Mongo DB(suggest if other tool is better). From the code, i need to specify the ConnectionString, right? Hackers or  other programmers cannot see these credentials. Here i need simple and best solution. The reason for asking this, i cannot spend too much money on buy any commercial softwares etc...

Please bare me if it looks simple question.

Comment: If you don't want your data to be visible to the users, don't keep it in their device, place it in your server. You can use any server you like, just do some research online to find which one suits you.

Comment: Can someone please help me here?

Comment: Can i use encrypted pass phrase in SQLCiper? If Yes, can someone help me how to do that?

Answer (score -1):

**SECURING ANDROID SQLITE DB WITH SQLCIPHER AND JNI**

1) SQLCipher :
SQLCipher is an open source extension to SQLite that provides transparent 256-bit AES encryption of database files.

Its provides support for Java, Python, Android, iOS, etc.

2) JNI (Java Native Interface):
As to secure it uses 256-bit AES algorithm which requires a key to encrypt or decrypt files.
So we have used JNI to store key securely.

How to integrate in project ?

Steps :

Create New Project
Give package name
Select option “Include c++ support”
Create activity and finish.
 Add the following line in build.gradle (app)
compile

> ‘net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:3.5.4’

Sync the project.

Comment: as i mentioned above, where we store the password or passphrase in SQLCipher?

Comment: SQLCipher is really intended to be used where key material is not included in the application package (i.e. not for use as DRM). In this model the key material comes from somewhere else (e.g. from the user in the form of a pin or password, or from some other means like a key service, secure keystore, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In this scenario aswell, the intended hacker / programmer can provide PIN and once the app is installed he can use the same PIN to explore the data, right? Or am i missing anything here?